# Laravel view not found 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, view

I am getting 1 error, which is very strange. 
**Error :** View [pages.email_templates.welcome_template_5] not found.

But the fact is that view file does exist in the mentioned folder.

I have tried following command but with no luck.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Controller :

```
$templatename = strtolower(str_replace(' ','_',$template_text->template_name));
return view('pages.email_templates.'.$templatename);
```

**Best Part :** Its working fine in localhost but  not in the server

Comment: take a screenshot of view directory or share complete view name and it's directory path

Comment: thanx. Its solved

Answer (score 2):

did you tried `php artisan dump-autoload` or `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: yeah, i did not have permission to just comment, sorry... but now i do...

Answer (score 1):

First You need to clear your application cache and configuration

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear

 $string1 = "pages.email_templates";
 $string2 = $templatename = strtolower(str_replace(' ','_',$template_text->template_name));

$page = sprintf("%s%s",$string1,$string2);

return view($page);
```

Autoload your all classes and class dependencies

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
composer dumpautoload
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear

$templatename = strtolower(str_replace(' ','_',$template_text->template_name));
return view('pages.email_templates.'.$templatename);
```

Comment: @RakeshTripathi: Glad to help and please if my answer work for you then accept my answer also upvote to my answer